# How to stop executing Java code and wait for ActionEvent?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, wait, notify

Just want to make sure if this approach is right if I want to wait for user interaction (waiting while user press some button):

```
SomeDialog someDialog = new SomeDialog(frame);

someDialog.setVisible(true);

try {

       synchronized (someDialog) {
          someDialog.wait();
       }

     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(SomeDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

int a = 0; a++; // <---- this line should not be processed before user clicks a button
```

And then:

```
someDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    synchronized (SomeDialog.this) {
       SomeDialog.this.notify();
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, `SomeDialog` class extends `JDialog` which is set `setModal(true);` (in this situation `JDialog` is used only for this method, otherwise I would use `JWindow`).

Comment: If you are setting dialog model, then it's parent window will always be blocked from user input. You do not have to do anything. Parent window will resume execution only after model dialog is disposed.

Comment: Yes, but the question is not about user input blocking, but how to hold further code processing. Everything works fine, just wanted to hear other opinions.

Comment: Code will also block from execution after you call dialog.setVisible(true); How you are creating dialog?

Comment: Just move that line of code into an `ActionListener`. It's really not a good idea to try and "wait" (on the EDT) when writing GUI code. It's possible for modal dialogs because they keep the UI responsive by starting a new event loop, but this isn't an option in the general case.

Comment: Actually the code is complicated, I can't move it in `actionPerformed` method, for me it is more convenient to do processing in separate class. Dialog is created from scratch (extends `JDialog`), just one method of `JDialog` is used `setModal(true)`. I think I will keep on using `wait()` and `notify()`.. Thnaks for help anyway.

Comment: insisting on doing thingies the wrong way is ... suboptimal ;-) -1 and voting to close, as the question isn't really answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `someDialog.setModal(true)` to if you need to wait for user to deal with your dialog before doing something else.

Comment: It is set so, but when it becomes visible, the code is processed further.., even the button is not pressed.